# Get geolocation by Javascript and save it to text file via php

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

I want to get latitude and longitude of the guest and save them to a text file..

I used this:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

 $location = print '
   <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
window.onload=function(){
if(navigator.geolocation)
{
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}
else
{
alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}
}
function showPosition(pos){
document.write("Location: "+pos.coords.latitude+","+pos.coords.longitude);
</script>
'

;



$Seb = "*******************" ;
 $file = "save.txt";
 $a = fopen($file, "a");
 fwrite($a,$location."\r\n");
    fwrite($a,$Seb."\r\n");
 fclose($a);


?>
<form action="index.php">
<input type="submit" value="Refresh">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

but the result in the text file is :

```
1
```

---

with out any geolocation data

Any Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally not how it works. As `javascript` is client-side, and `PHP` is server-side, you can't just do it the way you are trying to. You need to send that information to the server from client browser. The most common way, would be using `ajax` to POST `javascript` generatred content...

With jQuery it would be as easy as:

In html file...

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
if(navigator.geolocation)
{
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}
else
{
  alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}
}
function showPosition(pos){
   $.post('saver.php',{'lat':pos.coords.latitude,'lng':pos.coords.longitude},function(res){
      console.log(res);
   });
}
</script>
```

In **saver.php**

```
<?php
   print_r($_POST);
   $a = fopen("save.txt", "a");
   fwrite($a,"Location: $_POST[lat],$_POST[lng]\n*******************\n");
   fclose($a);
?>
```

PS. If you can't or don't want to use jQuery, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) for information on how to use ajax in raw javascript.

Comment: i am total noob with this but i just run this code and it doesn't save anything. what do i have to do  in order to create the safe.txt ?

Comment: First, you should check if your browser does support geolocation. Second, if it is on. Third, if it sends proper request to `saver.php`. If it does, the only thing left would be write permissions for PHP script.